# пропадает элемент, когда jquery объект конвертирую в массив

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
console.log($items, $items.length);
$items = $items.toArray();
console.log($items, $items.length);
```

Снимок из лога
[image: снимок из лога]
сначала в объекте 4 элемента, потом получаю массив из DOM элементов, `$items.length` так же 4, но консоль показывает, что длина массива 3. Перебор через forEach конечного массива так же не видит 1 элемент.

Comment: `.get();` - а что это за метод? что там внутри?

Comment: ```.get();``` работает так же как ```.toArray();``` и с ним та же самая ошибка.

Comment: что внутри я не смотрел, использую https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: а есть ссылка на документацию. Не нашел ни одного упоминания `get` за исключением ajax запроса

Comment: пусть будет ```$items = $items.toArray();``` ссылки на ```get``` у меня тоже нет.

Comment: исправил описание

Comment: "пусть будет $items = $items.toArray();". Нет. Не пусть будет то-то, а надо писать именно то, что используешь. А так можно гадать на хрустальном шаре. А в итоге окажется ты вообще используешь какие-то запросы, функции, еще какую-то библиотеку. Надо описать полностью и точно что используешь когда и привести полный пример

Comment: у тебя съедает объект что-то после последнего консоль-лога.  так как. его значение на момент вывода нормальное. смотри код ниже. пройди дебагером

Comment: т.е. пока console.log печатает массив, что-то ниже успевает его поменять?

Comment: Сергей Мишин вы придираетесь, я заменил функцию, чтоб было по документации, проблема осталась, мне кажется вы не помочь желаете, а докопаться

Comment: Сергей Петрашко да действительно, что-то ниже портит массив, а консоль отображает его в режиме реального времени. спасибо.

Comment: @shadow что и требовалось доказать - были всякие манипуляции, которые не были указаны в вопросе. Собственно о чём я и написал. А если бы я хотел докопаться, я бы уже и минус бы влепил и сказал, что в вопросе должен быть  [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), а не домыслы. Но конечно, легче же продираться через заросли и кустарники.